# Check if Container is Cached - Singularity

Tags: singularity-container

I am looking for a way to check if a container is already cached from a hub url. For example I would want a command to do something like:

```sh
singularity iscached docker://username/container:tag
True
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command

```
singularity cache list --verbose | grep 'IMAGE_NAME.sif'
```

if that return code is 0, then the image exists. you can get the return code with `$?`. you will have to change names like `docker://user/repo:tag` into the sif filenames that singularity creates.

for example:

```
singularity cache list --verbose | grep 'alpine_latest.sif'
echo $?  # prints 1
singularity pull docker://alpine:latest
singularity cache list --verbose | grep 'alpine_latest.sif'
echo $?  # prints 0
```

Comment: It seems to me that `singularity cache list -v` returns hashes of blobs/OCIs but not the actual containers, so you don't get the images name.

Comment: @pablacious - which version of singularity are you using?

Comment: I am using singularity version 3.8.7-1.el7 and can confirm that neither iscached OR cache list do not work.

Comment: i'm using singularity 3.6.3 and agree that `singularity cache list --verbose` doesn't show the image names. i must have been using an older singularity version when writing this answer.